# Why Django does not generate app name into href paths?

Tags: python, django

I hope someone could maybe help me, please :
I am quite new to Django and currently trying to implement a simple login/logout for a test page.
However, for some reasons, the Django does not generate the name of application in the href (so where it should be xxxx/main/register, it is only xxx/register).
But when I put the app name manually in the href in Pycharm, it generates it two times (so it becomes xxx/main/main/register).

So for this:

```
<a href="/logout/">Logout</a>
```

I got this url: 
http://127.0.0.1:8000/logout/

If I write this:

```
<a href="main/logout/">Logout</a>
```

I got this url: 
http://127.0.0.1:8000/main/main/logout/

But I need to get this:
http://127.0.0.1:8000/main/logout/

It worked before, but from one minute to another, it suddenly stopped directing to the good path. And django does the same thing with every links in my site.

main/urls.py:

```
from django.urls import path
from . import views

app_name = 'main'  # here for namespacing of urls.

urlpatterns = [
    path("", views.homepage, name="homepage"),
    path("register/", views.register, name="register" ),
    path("logout/", views.logout_request, name="logout"),
]
```

main/views.py:

```
from django.shortcuts import render, redirect
from django.http import HttpResponse
from .models import Tutorial
from django.contrib.auth.forms import UserCreationForm, AuthenticationForm
from django.contrib.auth import logout, authenticate, login
from django.contrib import messages

def homepage(request):
    return render(request = request,
                  template_name='main/home.html',
                  context = {"tutorials":Tutorial.objects.all})

def register(request):
    if request.method == "POST":
        form = UserCreationForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            user = form.save()
            username = form.cleaned_data.get('username')
            messages.success(request, f"New account created: {username}")
            login(request, user)
            return redirect("main:homepage")
        else:
            for msg in form.error_messages:
                messages.error(request, f"{msg}: {form.error_messages[msg]}")
    else:
        form = UserCreationForm
    return render(request = request,
              template_name='main/register.html',
              context={"form":form})

def logout_request(request):
    logout(request)
    messages.info(request, "Logged out successfully!")
    return redirect("main:homepage")
```

mysite/urls.py:

```
from django.contrib import admin
from django.urls import include, path

urlpatterns = [
    path('polls/', include('polls.urls')),
    path('main/', include('main.urls')),
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
    path('tinymce/', include('tinymce.urls')),
]
```

Comment: I would assume the `<base>` tag in your html document is not correct. Can you check and share the value of that first?

Comment: Hm, there is no base tag in the html code...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The behaviour you observe has **nothing** to do with Django, it's a basic html feature: in the first case you're using an absolute path (=> starting with a slash) for your href, in the second one you're using a relative path (NOT starting with a slash) so it's resolved relatively to the current url path whatever it is. You'd have the very same issue with plain static HTML.

This being said, in Django, you should never hardcode urls, but use the `{% url <name> %}` template tag (or the `django.utils.reverse()` function in Python code) instead, so you can change your urls in the urls.py files without breaking anything.

Comment: Thank you for your help, it resolved the problem completely and very neat explanation!

Answer (score 0):

You should use the url name in the template. It should solve the problem. Like this:
`<a href="{% url 'logout' %}">Logout</a>`

Or with namespacing: 
`<a href="{% url 'main:logout' %}">Logout</a>`

Comment: Thank you for your help! Unfortunately, still not working...
I get this message:
NoReverseMatch at /main/
Reverse for 'login' not found. 'login' is not a valid view function or pattern name.
Request Method: GET
Request URL: http://127.0.0.1:8000/main/
Django Version: 3.0.6
Exception Type: NoReverseMatch
...

Comment: So django cannot find the url with his name. I think it's because you are using namespacing in main/urls.py. try `<a href="{% url 'main:logout' %}">Logout</a>`

Answer (score 0):

```
<a href="{% url 'logout' %}">
```

Use the name in href tag that will work.